# When using MapKit, are MKAnnotations the model of MVC paradigm?

Tags: model-view-controller, ios5, mkmapview, mkannotation

When using MapKit, are MKAnnotations the model of MVC paradigm?
I mean, let's say I have locations (for instance, cinemas) and those can be shown using a map and a list (table view).
 What is the model in this context?
 I guess are Ciname instances, but MKMapView requires annotations (MKAnnotation and MKAnnotationView). Using the table I don't have problems, as I can use the model in cellForRow, but using MKMapView requires annotations.

Do I have to copy all cinemas to custom annotations?
I guess that's not normal.
What do you think? basically what I don't understand is how to use the model view controller pattern properly in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MkAnnotations is a protocol, so your objects (the modell) just must also implement that protocoll, that can work whitout copy.

So yes your objects that i plement that MkAnnoation protocoll is the modell, related to MVC.

This protocoll is neccessary for MkMapKit to have a coordinate for each object in the modell.

Comment: What about if I have something for clusterization or I don't shown all the points on the map? The MKMapView has an array of Annotations, isn't it that duplicating the data?

Comment: An Array of Annotations is an array of pointers to your Object that implements AMkAnnotation. Fur clustering: good question, I dont know, maybe change the annotation on the fly, and if that does not work fine, like in MKPolygon, then one has to use an own management and drawing.